# Redirect rule for AWS S3 bucket as in htaccess

Tags: amazon-web-services, .htaccess, amazon-s3, mod-rewrite

I have a website hosted on a apache server and I use this .htaccess rewrite rule to have website.com/article/title-here act like website.com/article.html?title=title-here

Here is the .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?article/([^/d]+)/?$ article.html?title=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The problem is that I want to move the website.com into an Amazon S3 bucket, but there the .htaccess is not working.

I tried using the rewrite rules for the static hosting as follows:

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <KeyPrefixEquals>article.html?title=</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>article/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have url rewrite or anything similar in S3.

S3 is **only a storage solution** not a full fledge web-server.

The closest thing you can get to what you want is to use CloudFront to set up a distribution and add `Custom Error Responses` that redirect on `404` and `403` to a known item (article in your case).